# Search for contents in a row and say which cell its in

Tags: excel

Hey I'm struggling how to search for contents in a row and to say which row its in.

I have two rows which have numbers, lets say

```
  1|2
123|12
 12|1
```

I'd want to be able to search the first row and say where it is in the second row

something like

if a1 is in row b, say which cell its in.

Could anyone help@?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32508878/edit) the question to clarify what you are looking for. `search for contents in a row and to say which row its in`, `row b`, formatting of sample data doesn't help much to understand the problem.

Comment: You say `row`, I think you mean `column`.  And the function you might be looking for is `vlookup` or `hlookup`  A1 data is found in B3  A3 is found in B2.. A2 is not found.  where would you want that to be displayed column C?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I *think* I see what you're asking.

First, you're confusing rows and columns.  Your sample data is in two columns, with three rows.

Let's say it looks like this (Starting in cell A1)

```
A      B
1      2
123    12
12     1
```

In cell C1, put `=IFERROR("Row " &MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$3,0),"")`.

It'll return this:

[image]

It takes a value in column A, and looks for it in column B.  If there's a match, it will return the text "Row " and the row number that it's found in in Column B.

Edit: If you want the actual cell (i.e. $A$1) that the matching value is found in, then use `=IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$3,0),1),"")`